# I get error on Adding custom action in symfony Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given

Tags: php, symfony, action, easyadmin

I have a dating website programmed with symfony. I want to add a function in easyadmin to be able to delete a user and her/his messages and posts. In UserCrudController I followed the instruction in symfony website and write a custom action. But I get an error

> > Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given

```
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        // this action executes the 'renderInvoice()' method of the current CRUD controller
        $delUserAction = Action::new('deleteUser', 'Delete user completely')
            ->linkToRoute('delete_user', function (User $user){
                $id = $user->getId();
                $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
                if ($res) {
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->remove($res);
                    $em->flush();
                }
                $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Message::class)->remove_all_message($id);
                $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Beziehungen::class)->remove_all_relations($id);
                $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Album::class)->remove_album_of_user($id);
                $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Blog::class)->remove_blog_of_user($id);
                $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Comment::class)->remove_comments_of_user($id);
                $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Subcomment::class)->remove_subcomments_of_user($id);
                $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Like::class)->remove_likes_of_user($id);
            });

        return $actions
            // ...
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $delUserAction)
            ;
    }
```

**Can you please help me?**

Answer (score 1):

According to the [tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/actions.html), [`linkToRoute`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/actions.html#adding-custom-actions) will connect an action to a route (as the name suggests). Similar to other route functions, it expects as first parameter the route name and as second parameter *an array or a function that returns an array* - the parameters to fill the placeholders of the route.

Your function doesn't return an array but instead IS the action.

So you really should put the deletion code you have and put it into an extra function like ... `deleteUserAction`, and then define your action as

```
$delUserAction = Action::new('deleteUser', 'Delete user completely')
    ->linkToCrudAction('deleteUserAction');
```